# HTML doesn't want to be executed

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3. Everything worked good, but today, I've experienced a big issue... When I load a page, I see the HTML and Javascript code, it appears like "text" in my explorer. And when I'm using CTRL+U, the source code is not colored...

Example :

[image]

I've ABSOLUTLY no idea of what the problem is... :/
Can you help me ? :)

Comment: probably you have a `header("content-type: text/plain");` or something in your code... which we can't tell because you didn't include it.

Comment: My wild guess is to check if apache is running. But hard to give you more advices without actual code

Comment: @PavelJanicek without the webserver running, OP wouldn't even get a connection.

Comment: Ok, then I have next wild guess Once something similar happened to me and it was made by simple typo error where I wrote `<? php` instead `<?php` with short brackets turned off

Comment: So what changed between it working and it not working.

Comment: please post the actual code, not a screenshot of the brower. the contents (or at least some of) the php file that is rendering this...

Comment: Is PHP actually installed? I don't think it is.

Comment: The first obvious diagnose would be to open the browser's Network pane and inspect the `Content-Type` header. It also won't hurt to hit Ctrl+U and see the raw output.

Comment: "Hey mechanic, I need to get my car repaired, just pls don't look under the hood, only listen to the engine! :)"  Can you at least show us the line that you return from the controller? Are you returning a Response or something else? Change the names of the files and sensitive logic.

Answer (score 1):

What did you use to write this code?

This can happen if the `< >` brackets are html encoded meaning `&gt; &lt;` was saved to the file instead of actual '<' and '>'

Open the file in a 100% plain text editor like notepad (Windows) or vim (Linux) and ensure the bracketing is actually what you think it is...

Comment: that would've been apparent then looking at the source code, i bet OP would've mentioned that. also, formatting would've been completely gone unless linebreaks and whitespaces were escaped too.

Comment: Not if you are using some strange editor to do this... Even without a webserver the html should render fine, its not a server side language..

Comment: i meant the source-code view of the browser, which OP clearly used (he said so). also: who would ever think of using a *strange* (ie: broken) editor like this? also: whithout a running webserver, he wouldn't get a *http connection to localhost*.

Comment: Whatever bud, just trying to help. Don't see you being constructive at all here... I'm offering possibilities and I have seen the example of what I have just said happen before...

Comment: I'll add this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this before you write anything in the output stream (echo any character):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This makes sure, your browser understand, that the document is a HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've finally founded the issue !

It was a problem with the configuration of FOSRestBundle, I had these lines :

```
    format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

And when I've removed it, the HTML works fine !

Comment: You could have got a hint on this if you had opened the browser's Network pane and inspected the Content-Type header.